# Render UILabel in multiple line in iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uilabel

I'm trying to render my `UILabel` in multiple line.
i've tried:

```
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(100, 45, 150, 60);
    FontLabel *addresLbl1 = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect2
                                                      fontName:@"arial" pointSize:12.0f];
    //#006000
    addresLbl1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:84/255.0 green:84/255.0 blue:84/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    addresLbl1.text = @"401 King St\\nToronto, Ontario, M5V1K1\\nCanada"; 
    //[addresLbl1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    addresLbl1.backgroundColor = nil;
    addresLbl1.opaque = NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addresLbl1];
    [addresLbl1 release];
```

but it is rendered as **401 King St\nToronto, Ontario, M5V1K1\nCanada**
Note that this label is added on cell of **UITableView**.
I need new line from the position of '\n' in string and this string will come from server, so position of '\n'may vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use doubble backslashes.

```
\\ is the code used for \, so \\n will be parsed and printed as \n
```

So you're code should be like this:

```
addresLbl1.text = @"401 King St\nToronto, Ontario, M5V1K1\nCanada";
addresLbl1.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default UILabel sets its property numberoflines to 1, which means your text will be rendered in one line. Try to set that property to 0, as indicated by the documentation

> This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to
>   fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value
>   for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many
>   lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.
>
> If you constrain your text using this property, any text that does not
>   fit within the maximum number of lines and inside the bounding
>   rectangle of the label is truncated using the appropriate line break
>   mode.
>
> When the receiver is resized using the sizeToFit method, resizing
>   takes into account the value stored in this property. For example, if
>   this property is set to 3, the sizeToFit method resizes the receiver
>   so that it is big enough to display three lines of text.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but i need new line from the position of '\n' in string and this string will come from server, so position of '\n'may vary.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple lines you can use UILabel property `numberOfLines` as

```
label.numberOfLines = 3;
```

In your case your text can fit only in one line so if you want it in multiple lines better you should define 3 different labels.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first set numberOfLines to 0, and then

```
unichar chr[1] = {'\n'};
NSString *singleCR = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)chr length:1];
[yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"new%@line",singleCR]];
```

this will ensure what you wanted.